# Remove Parent Keep Childs- DOM

Tags: java

This XML is input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ns0:EMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.abc/Something">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns0:Snumber>1613</ns0:Snumber>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Name>SomeEvent</ns0:Name>
    <ns0:NameSpace>http://www.abc/Something.xsd</ns0:NameSpace>
    <ns0:Id>3</ns0:Id>
    <ns0:myProperty>
        <ns0:Name>ExtId</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Value>TEST_ID_12</ns0:Value>
    </ns0:myProperty>
    <ns0:myProperty>
        <ns0:Name>CVersion</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:Value>0</ns0:Value>
    </ns0:myProperty>
</ns0:EMessage>
```

Convert to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<ns0:EMessage xmlns:ns0="http://www.abc/Something">
    <ns0:Header>
        <ns0:Snumber>1613</ns0:Snumber>
    </ns0:Header>
    <ns0:Name>SomeEvent</ns0:Name>
    <ns0:NameSpace>http://www.abc/Something.xsd</ns0:NameSpace>
    <ns0:Id>3</ns0:Id>
    <ExtId>TEST_ID_12</ExtId>
    <CVersion>0</CVersion>
</ns0:EMessage>
```

Basically what is needed is the parent tag should be removed and the childs should get the immideate child of ROOT.

LOGIC part

```
Node root = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns0:EMessage").item(0);

NodeList listOfNodes = root.getChildNodes();
int length_Child_nodes=listOfNodes.getLength();
System.out.println("length of child nodes for root element"+length_Child_nodes);
for (int i = 0; i < listOfNodes.getLength(); i++) {
    //  Node to be picked in click and this will be the element and will have childs.
    Node listItem = listOfNodes.item(i);
    Node Fchild=listItem.getFirstChild();
    String value="";
    if ("ns0:Name".equals(Fchild.getNodeName())) {
        Node oldChildNodeName=listItem.getFirstChild();
        Node Value=Fchild.getNextSibling();
        if("ns0:Value".equals(Fchild.getNextSibling().getNodeName())){
            value=Fchild.getNextSibling().getTextContent();
        }
        String localname=listItem.getFirstChild().getTextContent();
        Element newChildNode = doc.createElement(localname);
        //  Replace the existing node Property Name.
        listItem.replaceChild(newChildNode, oldChildNodePrpertyName);
        //                  Replace the existing node Property Value
        listItem.removeChild(Value);
        //System.out.println("remove child"+node.removeChild(oldChildNodePropertyValue));
        newChildNode.setTextContent(value);
        //System.out.println("new Node Name::"+newChildNode.getName());
        //System.out.println("OLD node::"+oldChildNodePrpertyName.getName());
        //System.out.println("newValue::"+newChildNode.getTextContent());
    }
}
```

The above code do the manipulation as required.But the Parent of all the childs that tag is needed to be removed.Which i am not getting through.And ideas would be great help for me.

Comment: It would really help if you would format both your XML and your code so they're easy to read, ideally without horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @JonSkeet   I used Ctrl+K,can you help me with other option.

Comment: Well you need to use Ctrl-K more for all but the first line of your code - notice how it's not indented in the same way as the first line. Then look at your XML - the root element is on the same line as the XML declaration, and the `Snumber` element isn't indented, etc. Basically, edit the post and keep editing it until it looks how you'd want to see it if *you* were reading it with a mind to answering.

Comment: I've already done it, take it as example for the next question/ answer. Now you can add a most precise information about your problem: you say the code does the required manipulation, so what's the problem?

Comment: Any help guys?Other than formatting and edits :P?

Comment: @Pablo: Required manipulation means,ns0:myProperty Element is the parent for ns0:Name and Value node now i am able to make changes in those two nodes but i need to remove this parent ns0:myProperty and make the ns0:Name and Value node as immideate child to the root of the document which is <ns0:EMessage> element.